# Ubuntu 14.04: How to add an Ethernet connection from command line that's editable in Network Manager GUI?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, network-manager, ethernet

On Ubuntu **14.04**, how can I add an **Ethernet** connection from **the command line** that's editable in the [Network Manager GUI](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8781/17139502730_c3ca920f7f.jpg)?

I have studied [nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html) which is the command line tool for the Network Manager. Unfortunately:

- If you compare the [nmcli tool on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html) and [that on Ubuntu 15.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/nmcli.1.html) documentation, you'll notice that 14.04 LTS doesn't support adding an Ethernet connection via the nmcli tool. The `add` command is added to nmcli's `connection` object since 15.10. It's **not** available on 14.04.
- The nmcli on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can connect to a wireless network (see the last example in its [document](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nmcli.1.html)), but I want to create an Ethernet connection.
- Although I can edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` to add the Ehternet interfaces, they are not visible in the Network Manager, and this is **not** what I prefer.

I'm doing this because I'm writing a shell script to configure the network, and I also want to allow the users to edit the configuration from the GUI when necessary.

Thanks in advance!

==========

UPDATE #1:

I forgot to mention [`nm-connection-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nm-connection-editor.1.html): As far as I can see, it is still a GUI tool and requires the user interaction to create/edit a connection. Because I'm trying to automate the process in a script, I don't want to use any GUI stuff here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit/create a connection file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. For instance I just created `ethfix192`

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full

[connection]
id=ethfix192
type=802-3-ethernet
autoconnect=false

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
address1=192.168.2.22/24,0.0.0.0
```

You will see how the lines in this file correspond to the settings in the GUI.

Note: Ensure that the file has permission '600', otherwise NetworkManager will ignore the file.

Afterwards you need to restart NetworkManager (IIRC on 14.04 it was with `sudo service NetworkManager restart`, or sudo `service network-manager restart`) and NetworkManager will recognize the connection.