# Mangage Network Connections from command line

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a virtual machine playing around with FOG and I want to try running FOG from a VM running Ubuntu server 16.04.4 LTS.

One step in order to get the connection to the FOG server to work is to:

- click the network icon in the top right corner of the screen
- click "Edit Connections..." from the drop down menu
- delete the existing network connection
- add a new ethernet connection
- under IPv4 settings for this connection, add an address with an IP for the server, the subnet mask, and the IP for the gateway
- save.

In order to accomplish this in ubuntu server, I need to do so from the command line, but I am not sure how.

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824435/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-add-an-ethernet-connection-from-command-line-thats-editabl) that I think would put me on the right track, but I was not able to produce the results I was looking for. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Typically, in Ubuntu server edition, Network Manager is not installed. If you are installing the classic server edition, the process varies depending on the exact version. 17.10 and later use netplan and earlier use /etc/network/interfaces. Please clarify these points.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server edition, Network Manager is not installed. Network Interfaces are configured in /etc/network/interfaces.

First, find the identifier for the interface from the command line:

```
ifconfig
```

It may be eth0. Using eth0 as an example, amend the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add to the existing loopback stanza, the following:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Of course, substitute your details here. Save and close the text editor. Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns, you’re all set.